# keyof typeof StaticClass seems to include the StaticClass' type itself

Tags: typescript

```
class LogFunctionMap {
  static error = (err: any) => `[[black]][[bred]]ERROR[[r]]   [[white]]${err}`;
  static outboundMessage = (message: GGMessage) => ``;
  static default = x => x
}

const log = <G extends keyof typeof LogFunctionMap>(loggedObject, logType: G) => {
  if (logType) {
    const fn: typeof LogFunctionMap[G] = LogFunctionMap[logType];
    fn(loggedObject);
  }
};
```

`fn(loggedObject);` yields a TypeScript error:

```
Error:(104, 5) TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type 'LogFunctionMap | ((err: any) => string) | ((message: GGMessage) => string) | ((x: any) => any)' are callable.
    Type 'LogFunctionMap' has no call signatures.
```

We see the type `LogFunctionMap` is included alongside the type of its members. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `<G extends keyof typeof LogFunctionMap>` apart from all methods includes a builtin `prototype` method. From the [TypeScript Language Specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cfb0adeadf1f21b5f8201cb2c0765f3f4467633f/doc/spec.md#825-constructor-function-types):

> The type of the constructor function introduced by a class declaration is called the constructor function type. The constructor function type has the following members:
>
> ...
>
> - A property named 'prototype', the type of which is an instantiation of the class type with type Any supplied as a type argument for each type parameter.

Therefore the type of `LogFunctionMap.prototype` is `LogFunctionMap`.

To get rid of the error you can just exclude `prototype`:

```js
const log = <G extends Exclude<keyof typeof LogFunctionMap, "prototype">>(loggedObject, logType: G) => {
  if (logType) {
    const fn: typeof LogFunctionMap[G] = LogFunctionMap[logType];
    fn(loggedObject);
  }
};
```